# net-snmp proxying part of the OID subtree

Tags: snmp

How can I get net-snmp snmpd to proxy requests related to specific subtree to a specific server and answer to other requests by itself?

I use Centos 5. Currently, I've configured snmpd  as described in [the net-snmp wiki entry](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmpd_proxy) and set up another snmp agent which answers for requests related to its own OIDs. It works fine when I interface with it directly.

Now, when I run snmpd with default options `-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a`, requests to OIDs from my subtree are never relayed to the defined agent. When I added  `-Iproxy` option, snmpd answers **only** for OIDs from the specific subtree, all other requests are answered with 'no such object' error.

What can I do to make snmpd answer for *all* available OIDs, to standard ones by itself and to those from specific tree by proxying? I admit that I'm a newbie with SNMP-related stuff, so I'll be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Can you post your full snmpd config (with changed community strings and comment lines removed) so we can see the whole picture?  It's hard to troubleshoot a problem when you can't see what all is going on.